# Algebra question - Formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Really having a hard time with this question. any help would be appreciated. 
Suppose that a cliff diver's height (in feet) after t seconds is given by the model $H = −16t^2+48t+28$ . Find the height after $1.75$ seconds.

Comment: Have you tried something? This looks pretty easy.

Comment: Yes, i plugged in a 1.75 for t and it did not work.

Comment: I plugged it in and got 63 without using 7/4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is $63$.

$1.75 = 7/4$, so:

$-16(1.75)^2+48\cdot 1.75 + 28 = -16\cdot\frac{49}{16}+48\cdot\frac 74 + 28 = -49 + 12\cdot 7+ 28 = 112-49 = 63.$